# how do i get styles of class 'a' for class 'b', when there is no relation between them?

Tags: javascript, css

so let us say i have a div with class 'a'.
it has some styles, for simplicity let us say a property color:'red'.
now i have another div with class 'b' and a property, color:'blue'.

i want to make it so, that the second div, has the styles of class 'b'
but should contain only class 'a' in the classList.

my approach is to give class 'b' styles, to class 'a' after removing all prev styles of class a
using all:'initial'.

but i can not make any changes to the stylesheet.
i have to use only js for this task.
i could type down js for each and every property, but there a lot of properties.

is there something similar to all:'inherit'?
also, there is no relation between the divs. no parent-child or sibling relation.

tl;dr:  a way in which, a class can get all properties of another class, when there is no meaningful relation between the two

Comment: So copy over the styles with JavaScript, there is not really much you can do. Is it a known list of properties?

Comment: Why is there a limitation of "has the class of 'b' but should only class 'a' in the classList"?

Comment: @epascarello yes it is a known list of properties. so is copying in js the only way?

Answer (score -1):

If you really don't want to change the stylesheet and want to use JavaScript then I think this will do it:

```
//It will add all the styles of "class a" to the element containing "class b" And I hope you know what to do when you need to do the opposite.
document.querySelector('.b').classList.add('a');
```

Note: You are not only just assigning the styles of "class a" to the element containing "class b" but also you are assigning that class.

So if these classes are just for styling then it is totally OK to use this method. But if there are any other functions of those classes then it might affect them.